# Using Points As Keys For HashTables Always Returns Nulls

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to use a hashtable to store and retrieve values for indices of a matrix.

```
Hashtable<Point, Integer> sparseMatrix = new Hashtable<Point, Integer>();
```

Each point has an x and a y, with an override function for toString to make it comprehensible.

```
public class Point {

    int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int[] pos() {
        return new int[] {x, y};
    }

    public int[] reverse() {
        return new int[] {y, x};
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return String.format(x + "," + y); 
    } 

}
```

When you print out the hashtable, you get `{1,1=7, 2,1=9, 1,2=8, 3,1=11, 3,2=12, 2,2=10}` so I definitely know that values are being stored, and the keys are being formatted the way I want.

So, why, when I type `sparseMatrix.contains((new Point(1,1)))` I always receive false despite clearly having a value there?

I feel like there is something fundamental I'm missing about identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `hashCode and equals` for your `key` to work  properly.

```
public int hashCode() {
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
}
```

Read the `Map` interface description [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) for details.

I modified your class to add the methods.  You should still read about it ensure you understand the issues.

```
class Point {

    int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         return x*31 + y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o instanceof Point) { 
           Point p = (Point) o;
           if (p.x == this.x && p.y == this.y) {
               return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int[] pos() {
        return new int[] {x, y};
    }

    public int[] reverse() {
        return new int[] {y, x};
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return String.format(x + "," + y); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its been so long since I've used java, I've forgotten all the catch-ups.

Comment: Once you read up on it you may want to modify equals to support nulls.  Some classes do it, others don't.  If you pass a null value to equals you will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

HashTable `contains` method check whether particular value is mapped to any keys in hashtable.

**Syntax**
HashTable.contains(Object value)

If you want to check corresponding to `key` use
`containsKey` method

**Syntax**:
HashTable.containsKey(key_element).

Since in your case you are checking corresponding to `Point` which is `key` use `containsKey` method of HashTable

Comment: Unfortunately, "System.out.println(sparseMatrix.containsKey((new Point(1,1))));" still returns false.

Comment: This is because you are creating new object reference of `Point` through new operator and passing. For example if we do Point p1 = new Point(1,1);Hashtable<Point, Integer> ht = new Hashtable<Point, Integer>();ht.put(p1, 1);ht.get(p1) it will return true . But since new object reference is created in your code for same Point values,   you need to override hashcode and equals method as mentioned by @WJS below